# Adblock Plus on firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, adblock, firefox-extensions

I wonder if there is a way to make Adblock plus work under firefox just like it is working under Chrome. Particularly the way that I specify ad on the page in Chrome is perfect. I just have to roughly specify ad location and there is a slider to extend the block. However, I can't find this in Firefox Adblock extension. Is there any way to have such way of specifying ads under firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution for Firefox an extension called [Element Hiding Helper for Adblock](http://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper). It's not exactly same, but somehow better than what is default.

Answer (score -1):

No, Adblock Plus for Firefox<sup>*</sup> does not provide such a context menu<sup>**</sup> and this is not possible.

<sup>*</sup>*Note thatAdBlock Plus for Chrome was [not originally written](http://qux.us/adthwart/) by the developers of ABP for Firefox.* 
<sup>**</sup>*though that context menu does appear when you right click on an image or a flash element.*